# Is there a pre-trained German sentiment analyzer in flairNLP?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm currently looking at a sentiment analysis task on text messages in German. The Flair library for Python seems to have a pretty powerful pre-trained model for English, but I can't find any comprehensive answer to whether it also contains a similar thing in German. I've tried googling the issue but got nowhere, and also attempted exchanging

```
flair.models.TextClassifier.load('en-sentiment')
```

for

```
flair.models.TextClassifier.load('de-sentiment')
```

and the same with 'ger-sentiment' and 'ge-sentiment' just in case that would work by some lucky fluke. However, I have so far gotten nowhere.

I am aware of textblob-de and will try that, but wanted to ask whether I missed something in Flair.

Comment: I am also working in a project where my text is in German. I also thought to do the same "trick" using `flair.models.TextClassifier.load('en-sentiment')` but as you said it won't work.

I found this article which you may find useful:
[https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-grained-sentiment-analysis-in-python-part-1-2697bb111ed4]

Comment: I am also looking for the same answer. Have you find any solution for this problem? However, the link provided by Ledian is broken.